# Disable flatpak automatic updating

Tags: flatpak

How are `flatpak`-installed packages updated? Is it like `snap` in that it performs automatic updating?

I don't want automated updating, only manually (like with `apt`). How do I configure that?

I'm using ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatpaks are not automatically updated without any input from the user. The following commands are handy:

- `flatpak remote-ls --updates`: list runtimes and applications that have updates available.
- `flatpak update [REF...]`: update application or runtime
- `flatpak update`: update all applications and runtimes

Contrary to `apt`, there is no need to manually update the package cache before querying the remote repository.